# Splitting a string into sub-strings with split.String("");

Tags: java

Say I have a string:

```
String temp = "One Two   Three     Four";
```

And I want to get each of the words of this string, if it was one space I'd use:

```
String[] splitTemp = temp.split(" ");
```

How do I do it for varying amounts of white space?
Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
temp.split("\\s+");
```

this makes all the white space a single delimiter.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response  :)

Answer (score 0):

Split accepts a regex argument, e.g. `temp.split("\\s+")` that matches one or more whitespace characters.